# Finding the value of x, $x=\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+....} } } } $

Tags: sequences-and-series, nested-radicals

I want to find the value of x where x is given by the following: $$x=\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+....} } } } $$
Noting that the above can be written in the following form: $x=\sqrt{0+x} $, we have $x=0$ or $x=1$
It seems that $x=0$ and $x\ne 1$, however I don't know how to reject the possibility that $x\ne 1$. Any help is appreciated. 
Edit: From the comments, I have understood that the question lacks details. This is because the above nested radical can be produced either by the sequence $a_1=0, a_{n+1}=\sqrt{0+a_n}$ or by $a_1=c \gt 0, a_{n+1}=\sqrt{0+a_n}$, which converge to 0 and 1 respectively. And therefore, both the answers x=0 and 1 are correct.

Comment: Try rigorously defining the nested root as a limit.

Comment: What is the precised definition of your $x$? If you have a precise definition, the answer should be obvious.

Comment: Try this: $x=5$, now square both side you get $x^2=25$. Solving this would result $x=5$ or $x =-5$. Squaring gives you multiple results.

Comment: @KentaS Additional hint: Anything containg "$\ldots$" is probably not rigorously defined

Comment: Hint: you can delete each $0+$.

Comment: Why do you have an infinity at the end of your nested roots?

Comment: @SomeGuy: edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a formal proof, use mathematical induction on $n=$ the number of square root radicals in each term of the sequence.

- At $n=1$ you clearly have $\sqrt0=0$.
- Assume you have $0$ for $n=k$.  Then the next term with $n=k+1$ is $\sqrt{0+0}$ thus proving the propagation of the $0$ value for all terms.

Comment: So I'll define $a_1=0$ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{0+a_n}$ and by induction $a_n=0 \forall n\in  N$

Comment: Exactly: $a_{n+1}=(0+a_n)^{1/2}$; $a_1=0$; Defined recursively. All terms of the sequence $a_n=0$, hence the limit $=0$.

Comment: One can however also define $a_1=1$ or more general $a_1>0$.

Comment: @user,  So the above nested radical can be 0 and 1 as well. This is because if we define a sequence $a_1 = c \gt 0$ and $a_{n+1}= \sqrt{0+a_n}=c^{1/2^n}$ Hence $\lim (a_n)=1$. However, if we define $a_1=0 $ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{0+a_n}$, then $\lim(a_n) =0$

Comment: @Koro Exactly...